# Cocoa : How to set the delegate of a specific text field in a Table Cell View of a NSOutlineView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nsoutlineview, delegation

I would like to set the delegate of a TextField in a Table Cell View of my view based NSOutlineView. I try to se it like this :

```
-(NSView *)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn item:(id)item
{
    NSView *myView = [outlineView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"FinderItemRowType" owner:self];

    NSArray *mySubviews = [myView subviews];

    for (NSView *view in mySubviews)
    {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[NSTextField class]])
        {
            [(NSTextField *)view setDelegate:self];
        }

    }
    return myView;
}
```

This does not seems to work as the delegate methods are not triggered.
Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: That code doesn't look very "specific" as it sets all textfield's to the same delegate.

Comment: That is just a momentary placeholder as I only have 1 NSTextField... Thanks...